# DAO Smart Contract on Cardano

Tags: plutus, plutus-starter

Are there any resources available specific to creating a DAO on Cardano? I am interested in seeing any examples of DAOs on Cardano or technical articles on this topic. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting proposal in Fund 8 that you may find useful.

https://cardano.ideascale.com/c/idea/397172/comments

or here on Ada Pulse https://adapulse.io/agora-a-plutus-governance-module/